# IoT types of traffic

Tags: mobile-data, data-transfer

What are the types of traffic (bulk, burst, asynchronous, ...) that we can observe between IoT devices and clients (or base stations/collectors)?

Can we find a survey on this subject?

I am also interested in use cases that can help me to understand the types of traffic. For instance, could we find applications where:

1. Clients make queries to an IoT device (e.g. to a Data Base, maybe reduced to a single data that can undergo updates over time)
2. IoT devices send data (e.g. sensor measures) directly to an user on a regular basis.
3. Same as point 2) but IoT devices could send data to a collector on a regular basis, this latter being queried by a client at a later time. I think this use case exists (e.g. Wireless Sensor Networks)
4. Same as point 3), but instead the collector is queried by a client, it sends to the client data aggregates on a regular basis.
5. ...

Comment: I don't believe there's a survey on this subject, and I imagine it would be extremely difficult to effectively catalogue each and every device's method of connection (along with the difficulty of deciding whether this 'counts' as an IoT device and should be included in the survey). I think this question might be a little broad for our format, by the way. Take a read of [ask] for some tips—generally, asking for the use cases of several different connection modes is difficult to answer in one post. Instead, you should [edit] to narrow down to one specific case, so we can help you out. Good luck!

Comment: I think you have mistaken the use of IoT here. It's not a special new subset of the internet, it is more a way of looking at how use cases expand as the implementation costs drop (driven by a combination of hardware and infrastructure). Literally every type of traffic (and more) might be relevant to an IoT application in some time.

Comment: Are you interested in which protocols are used? It sounds more like you are interested in *how* they are used

Comment: For such broad questions maybe you can visit some of the IoT related conferences. Informa "Internet of Things Word" [https://tmt.knect365.com/iot-world/] is good example.

Comment: @Mawg You are right, I'm interested in how they are used and what kind of traffic they generate.

Comment: @Dingo13 If you're able, you should try to edit to narrow this down, keeping all the guidance in the comments in mind. Your question can still be reopened once you do that, and if you have one specific question, it's far easier for us to guide you to something that might be answerable.